# 'CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h' file not found

Tags: ios6, frameworks, zxing

When  I run a iOS App on my device , This error will appear

'CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h' file not found

not matter what project even though  create a new project , once run the app on my device this error will appear

but the Simulator will be OK～

and  I can't find  some frameworks in

Target--Build Phase--Link Binary With Librares--add

like AVFoundation.framework   AudioToolBox.framework

Should i reinstall the xcode on my mac~???

Answer (score 1):

Make certain you've added the CoreVideo framework to your project.

Here's how I do it in my own projects:

[image: Add CoreVideo project]

If you need help figuring out where it is (it's hidden within the XCode app package itself), let me know and I can show you.

Also, make certain "Target Membership" is checked for CoreVideo in the File Inspector of your project.  It looks like this:

[image: Target Membership Set, right?]

Comment: I add the CoreVideo Framework to my project ,the error is still there

and the project is new create I did nothing in it

Comment: Are you still getting the "can't find CoreVideo" error?  can you show me the "`#import`" line?  what other errors are you getting?

Comment: My project is just a new project , I did nothing ~~~~Just create and build ~
error line"

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreImage/CoreImageDefines.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>//error

The place it occur is iPhoneOS6.1>>Frameworks>>CoreImage.framework>>CIImage.h

Comment: Maybe "Target Membership" needs to be set?

Comment: I did as what you said ,I  think the error is not from this specified  framework ,maybe something goes wrong in my project , I'm downloading the  newly xcode