# CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h' file not found in ios7 and ios6

Tags: ios, frameworks, core-video

I'm facing one problem i.e. 
I don't want the `CoreVideo` or `CoreAudio` frameworks in app. So, I  din't add these frameworks. CoreImage framework is also not Added. But while running the App, in CoreImage Framework -> CIImage.h class showing the Error `Corevideo/CoreVideo.h file NotFound`.
Please any one suggest me how to resolve this.
I had already refer the link,
['CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513742/corevideo-corevideo-h-file-not-found)
But I didn't get proper solution.

Comment: So you want your app to run something that relies on that frameworks without adding them ?

Comment: Yes Exactly.How to achieve that...

Comment: Why dont u just include these frameworks